# What determines .NET version subfolder and HintPath for a NuGet package and how can we change them?

Tags: tfs, nuget, tfsbuild, nuget-package, nuspec

I created a custom NuGet package that targets .NET Framework 4.6.2. When I add it to a (also 4.6.2) project in Visual Studio, it creates the correct folder inside `packages` with my DLL under `lib\net462`.

However, the behavior is not the same in a TFS vNext build with a NuGet Package Restore step - it places it under `lib\net461`... HintPath in the .csproj file is still `net462` and the build fails as it doesn't find the DLL.

How is the location of a NuGet package determined when installing it? Same question with `HintPath`? How can I specify them so as to avoid bad surprises during builds?

Config info:

MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe both locally and in the TFS build

Visual Studio 2017 15.8.8

Comment: When a nuget restore run's it says what version of MSBuild it found and is using? Could this be the case (e.g. using MSBuild 12 from VS2013 still) - or could it be an older version of Nuget? Can you share if you are using the vNext (azure pipelines) builds or the XAML builds?

Comment: @DaveShaw it says `"Description : Build with MSBuild and set the Visual Studio version property"` and `"Version  : 1.120.0"`. And further in the logs - `"Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe"` which is the same as on my local machine. It's vNext builds.

Comment: Can you please edit the question and give more details about the projects. Are they "old" project files, or the new SDK project files? The project that gets packed, do you have a nuspec, or let nuget automatically generate one from the msbuild project? Is it multitargeted (both net461 and net462), or does it only target one? Does it have a `<TargetFramework>` node? The project that uses the package, is does it use packages.config, or PackageReference? does that project have `<TargetFramework>`?